# Set Facebook Photo as Album Cover

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on the API for a mobile application, which for the sake of argument is much like Foursquare and Instagram. Both of those applications will allow you to upload photos to your Facebook profile.

These will be added to a "Foursquare Photos" album, which will be made if it does not exist and you see it in your "Albums" area. Every time you add a new image it will become the album cover and you will see it displayed at the start of your album, so that images are in reverse chronological order (newest at the top/left, oldest bottom right).

To set the cover I assumed I could simply do this:

[image]

That is my attempt to post an update to the album ID, setting `cover_photo` as the photo ID of a file I've just uploaded. I have created the album fine, uploaded the photo fine all using the same access token - so we know it's not scopes (because yes I definitely have `user_photos` on the token).

A second approach was to assume this is automatic and try uploading a photo to the "start" of an album using the "position" field, but when I make a POST it seems to be completely ignored:

```
$photo = $facebook->api("/{$album_id}/photos", 'POST', array(
    'access_token' => $token->oauth_token, 
    'image' => '@'.$filename,
    'no_story' => 1, 
    'position' => 1,
    'from' => array(
        'id' => $user_opp->user->facebook_uid,
    ),
));
```

That uploads the image fine, but puts it at the end of the album, not the start.

So, how the f**k does this work? I've Googled my arse off and got nowhere. Tried the IRC and had no response, tried the Facebook Developer forums and they're down. I don't have any goats to sacrifice but maybe somebody out there knows.

Comment: I've had a suggestion that the position field being ignored by the POST method is probably a bug, so I have filed a bug report with Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/532976626728071

Comment: In my experience, Facebook always uses the last photo in an album as the cover. Not intuitive, but it seems to be the case.

Comment: That is what is supposed to happen, but it doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm...we struggle with the fact that we send a `batch` of photos. So, although Facebook uses the last photo, it is impossible to predict 100% which photo will be last.  :)

Answer (score 2):

> Every time you add a new image it will become the album cover and you will see it displayed at the start of your album

That should happen automatically. And in my tests, it does.

> A second approach was to assume this is automatic and try uploading a photo to the "start" of an album using the "position" field, but when I make a POST it seems to be completely ignored

That was never intended as a parameter for *posting* new photos, it was only returned when *reading* an albums photos from the API; and besides,

> https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#october-2012
>
> **Removing position field for photos:** The position field in both the photo FQL table as well as the Photo Graph API object will start returning 0 for all photos. The photos connection on an Album object in the Graph API will continue to return photos in the order they appear in the album.

Comment: It doesn't happen automatically for me. All new photos are added to the end of the album and the same cover photo remains in use no matter how many photos I post.

Comment: And as for the position field, I've never seen it returned. If it's been deprecated or simple emptied then why is it still documented without a note on there? I realise this was an assumption and not documented functionality, but there is no other logical explanation of how this should work. How do I change the order of photos? How do I make the album display reverse chronological order like Foursquare does?